# Is there a way to set minimum size of a LineChart in javafx to less than 200x150 pixels?

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am trying to display 24 LineCharts on a window [4 rows and 6 columns as shown in the picture. The window size is 1368x912 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV1YP.png).

The problem I am facing is that I need to show 24 LineCharts on a smaller window than shown on the upper image, but the smallest size of a LineChart is 200x150 px (at least I can't make it smaller).

Is there any way to overwrite the LineChart class to enable it to make it smaller?

Comment: Yes, I've done that before with line charts to make [spark lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline).  I don't recall what I did though and no longer have the code.  I think it required some code or custom CSS or both to remove axes and change styling.

Comment: Thank you, you've gave me just enough info to do it. I just had to remove padding from the charts using css.

Comment: As you have working code at hand, please consider an [answer to your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Also consider [tag:jfreechart-fx] for thumbnails, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40441186/230513).

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching, I found the solution to be quite simple.

You need to overwrite the maxSize and minSize properties of the lineChart with the same size:

```
lineChart.setMaxSize(double, double);
lineChart.setMinSize(double, double);
```

If the minimum size is bigger than the maximum size, the minimum size will overrule.

You can also adjust padding of a chart using a css file, which can be imported like this:

```
lineChart.getStylesheet().add("path/to/stylesheet.css");
```

Reference for [fx-css.](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#charts)